# How to make sure if parameter is a list of numbers? (python)

Tags: python, parameters

I've been working on [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and I got everything working fine, but I want to make sure user will enter proper input.

**I need statement checking if entered value is a list containing exactly two numbers, let it be integers or floats.** More info is always welcome.

If anyone needs the code, here you go. (There's probably just a formula for it somewhere, and this here is inefficient. ^^)

```
#finding a point on vector based on start point, end and %
def findPoint(t, A, B):
    '''
    findPoint( 'float member of <0, 1>',
               'coordinates of point A written as [x, y]',
               'coordinates of point B written as [x, y]')
    '''
    x=(B[0]-A[0])*t+A[0]
    y=(B[1]-A[1])*t+A[1]
    return [x, y]

#find coordinates of a point on the bezier curve
def bezierCurve(t, *points):
    pointList=[]
    for X in points:
        pointList.append(X)
    while len(pointList) !=1:
        tempList=[]
        for i in xrange(0, len(pointList)-1):
            tempList.append(findPoint(t, pointList[i], pointList[i+1]))
        pointList=tempList
return pointList.pop()
```

Comment: Separate the checking of user input for valid values from the usage of such a function. User input is to be checked and coerced as appropriate, but passing not-numbers to the bezierCurve is a *programming error* that violates the API contract and all sane bets are off. It is often not appropriate/recommend to include such checks at the usage-site in a dynamically typed language like Python.

Comment: @user2864740 Now that you mention it, I could agree. I'm pretty new to this stuff and I really dislike when giant error pops up on my screen, so I'd better recieve small message telling me I done goofed.

Comment: While I say it's generally not recommend, I become upset when JavaScript libraries throw "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" instead of "Supply an array, dummy" messages D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check that all of the elements are `int` (or `float`) by using `all`

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> all(isinstance(i, int) for i in l)
True
>>> all(isinstance(i, int) for i in a)
False
```

Also you could check that `len(list) == 2`

So as a function it could be something like

```
def twoNumValues(myList):
    return len(myList) == 2 and all(isinstance(i, int) or isinstance(i, float) for i in myList)
```

Or

```
def twoNumValues(myList):
    return len(myList) == 2 and all(type(i) in [float, int] for i in myList)
```

Comment: So basically on top of that I add 'and len(l)==3'? Also, that doesn't quite include possibility that user entered float, which is acceptable.

Comment: Please see my most recent edit. You can modify the list comprehension to allow both `int` and `float` if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one line function to test the parameters you describe:

```
def check(l):
    return len(l) == 2 and all(type(i) in (int, float) for i in l)
```

First check that the length is exactly 2, then check that both (all) of them are either int or float.